# require or include statements not working in facebook app but working locally correctly

Tags: php, facebook

I just started with facebook app development.

Problem is that require statement is not working.Even i tried 2 different simple php scripts with include & require statements,It is not locally on wamp server correctly but not as facebook app.

What should i do to get this done??
Code:

```
<?php
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo "your id id".$user;
?>
```

It is only printing your id is.Even facebook.php and other files are at right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` throws an error if the file can not be found/accessed. If you don’t see anything like that, first make sure you’ve set up `error_reporting` and `display_errors` in your PHP development environment right. If still no messages appear, than there *is* no real problem with embedding the SDK; more likely getUser just returns `null` or `false`, and so you just don’t see anything when echo-ing it. Please use `var_dump` in cases like this, it’ll tell you exactly what type and value a variable really has.

These are absolute *basics* of PHP debugging – please get a little more used to this, maybe work through some tutorials on the matter, before continuing developing PHP apps for Facebook.

Comment: In my case include or require statement is not working.I have tried by putting echo statement before and after.But echo statement after require is not printing.Problem is when i am trying it to wamp server it's working correctly.Only when i am deploying to facebook,It is showing nothing.

Comment: __Then set the error reporting to appropriate values!__ Scripts don’t die silently in case of such errors, unless you force them to.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I have setup error reporting and traced that include directory was not setted properly.